# show current user information from node to angular

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I want to show current user information from nodejs to angular(view).

The problem is that i don't know how to pass and how to get **User Id** in node and angular .

Code :

**Node**

```
router.get('/:id/api/data.json', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.params.id);
    var userId = req.params.id;
    User.findById({_id:userId}, function (err, doc) {
        if (err) throw err
        if (doc){
            res.json({
                doc: doc,
                userID:req.params.id
                });
        }
    });
});
```

**Angular :**

```
 app.controller('profileCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("don't know how to get id from node").then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.data);
    });
});
```

Comment: What is output in your browser when you `console.log(response.data)`? Also, have you tried user `res.jsonp()` instead of `res.json()`? The rest looks good to me.

Comment: the problem is that i don't know what should i put in url : $http.get("don't know how to get id from node")

Comment: Ah, sorry - I skimmed over that part too quickly. You just put in the url that Node is watching: `$http.get('/' + id + '/api/data.json').then...` Since Node is watching `'/:id/api/data.json'` this is the url you have to make the `$http.get` request to.

Comment: i got this error : id is not defined

Comment: From Angular/your browser? You would need to pass in an ID as a variable. I'll explain in an answer below so I can be a bit more thorough.

Comment: thanks , for sharing your information with me, i'm waiting fot this

Answer (score 1):

Your Node.js router is listening to the url `/:id/api/data.json`. The `:id` part of that means Node.js is expecting a paramater there, which will get picked up by `req.params.id` in your Node.js file.

This means that you actually have to be passing in an `id` value as a part of the url. So your url would look something like `/userid12345/api/data.json`.

In your Angular file, that's the url you're going to be making the `get` request to. Which means you need to know the user's ID in your Angular file so you can `get` that specific url, e.g.:

```
var userId = 'userid12345';

$http.get('/' + userId + '/api/data.json').then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

Once you pass `userId` in as a part of the url, then Node can grab it using `req.params.id` and you can make your db call.

Comment: i did this and i got error too : var id = userId
i got id is not defined

Comment: `id` and `userId` are just variables that I made up. Do you have an actual user ID in your database? If so, use that, then set your variable in your Angular file to the user ID in your database, i.e. `var userId = 'whatever user id is in your database';`

Comment: _id is in my mongo db , var userId = _id ; i got that error again

Comment: `_id` is set for every db entry in mongo db. What's the value associated with `_id` in your mongo db entry? It should look something like `574eef74555erss983290f283`.

Comment: yes it's something like this 574eef74555erss983290f283, but how can i pass this Id (dynamiclly) to angular controller ?

Comment: If you have an authentication package (like Passport), then the authentication package can take care of passing the user information to/from the browser. If you're using one of the MEAN stacks (mean.io or meanjs.org), they already have this set up. I use meanjs.org, and authentication is already set up, making it very easy. But overall, I would very much recommend an authentication package to manage this for you.

Comment: ok thanks for suggestion , no it's just angular and jade and mongo that have set up manually. i can show user info without angular , but i got error with angular , thanks anyway

Comment: Btw i forgot , i am using Passport , so is this help ?